# Pass a method as argument to another method that itself passes the passed method to std thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class called `MyClass` that contains two similar but slightly different non-static methods that compute something. The computation of each method can be done in parallel. Let's call them `void procedure1(int a, int b)` and `void procedure2(int a, int b)`. Both methods can be execute in parallel through `std::thread` and both take the same arguments. In my main execution, `procedure1()`gets called first, finishes (the threads join) and later  `procedure2()` gets called. I want to standardise invoking parallel execution of either of those two methods using a third method, lets call it `void exe_par(int a, int b, void (MyClass::*procedure)(int , int))`. This way I can just pass `procedure1` or `procedure2` to `exe_par` within my main execution method, See an example below.

To be clear I am aware of how to pass a method of a class to another method of a class as an argument and also how to pass a method of a class to `std::thread`in general. I am specifically interested in passing a method to `std::thread` that has been passed as as an argument to the method that initialises all my threads.

```
Class MyClass {

    void procedure1(int a, int b) { // does something // }

    void procedure2(int a, int b) { // does something // }

    void exe_par(int a, int b, void (MyClass::*procedure)(int, int)) {

        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        for(int thread = 0; thread < 4; ++thread) {
            threads.emplace_back(std::thread( // pass procedure somehow here //, a, b)
        }

        for(auto iter = threads.begin(); iter != threads.end(); ++iter){
            iter->join();
        }
     }

    void main_exe() {
        int a = 2 // I know this is stupid, for sake of simplicity
        int b = 2 // I know this is stupid, for sake of simplicity
        exe_par(a, b, &MyClass::procedure1)
        // some other sequential code here
        exe_par(a, b, &MyClass::procedure2)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
void exe_par(int a, int b, void (MyClass::*procedure)(int, int)) 
{
  //...
  threads.emplace_back(std::thread(procedure, this, a, b));
  //   first param is pointer to member function, 
  //   second param is pointer to object on which member function is called
  //   the rest is arguments for member function
```

[DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36a006f152371b97)